# Java Graphics2D Pan and Zoom

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have an image that I am rendering in a panel.  I would like the ability to zoom into the image and pan around.  While I could do this manually by recalculating the draw area, font, and line widths / locations, I suspect that there might be a better way.  If I draw the image to a bufferedImage or similar buffer, is there some Java facility that would give me pan and zoom for "free"?

Comment: Nothing in Java is free.  You have to code everything.  One way to get a pan function is to put your drawing JPanel in a JScrollPane.  Zoom requires you to keep a full size drawing on a BufferedImage, and scale the BufferedImage to the appropriate size before drawing on the drawing JPanel.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, thanks Gilbert. If I render the full size drawing once in a BufferedImage, as I zoom in, will it become pixelated or will Java essentially re-render it with each zoom to keep the font, rectangles, and lines smooth?

Comment: The full-size image is the maximum zoom image.  You zoom out from the full-size image.  You may have to break the full-size image into tiles to have your application fit in memory.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, thanks, that might work.  I'll try it.